# For each unique occurrence in field, transform each unique occurrence in another field in a different column

Tags: awk

I have a file

```
splice_region_variant,intron_variant    A1CF    1
3_prime_UTR_variant     A1CF    18
intron_variant  A1CF    204
downstream_gene_variant A1CF    22
synonymous_variant      A1CF    6
missense_variant        A1CF    8
5_prime_UTR_variant     A2M     1
stop_gained     A2M     1
missense_variant        A2M     15
splice_region_variant,intron_variant    A2M     2
synonymous_variant      A2M     2
upstream_gene_variant   A2M     22
intron_variant  A2M     308
missense_variant        A4GNT   1
intron_variant  A4GNT   21
5_prime_UTR_variant     A4GNT   3
3_prime_UTR_variant     A4GNT   7
```

This file is sorted by `$2`

for each occurrence of an unique element in `$2`, I wanna transform in a column each unique occurrence of an element in `$1`, with corresponding value in `$3`, or `0` if the record is not there. So that I have:

```
            splice_region_variant,intron_variant  3_prime_UTR_variant intron_variant downstream_gene_variant synonymous_variant missense_variant 5_prime_UTR_variant stop_gained upstream_gene_variant
    A1CF    1 18 204 22 6 8  0 0 0
    A2M     2 0  308 0  2 15 1 1 22
    A4GNT   0 7  21  0  0 22 3 0 0
```

test file:

```
a       x       2
b,c     x       4
dd      x       3
e,e,t   x       5
a       b       1
cc      b       2
e,e,t   b       1
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
        a       b,c     dd      e,e,t   cc

x       5               2       4       3
b       1       2       1
```

EDIT: This might be doing it but doesn't output `0`s in blank fields

```
'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
    NR > 1 {data[$2][$1] = $3; blocks[$1]}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"

        # header
        printf "gene"
        for (block in blocks) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, block
        }
        print ""

        # data
        for (ts in data) {
            printf "%s", ts
            for (block in blocks) {
                printf "%s%s", OFS, data[ts][block]
            }
            print ""
        }
    }' file
```

modified from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424642/dynamic-transposing-rows-to-columns-using-awk-based-on-row-value

Comment: Please specify the error you have been facing and what you have tried to resolve it. Also, the less code you post, the more likely it is someone will take a look at it -- so I'd recommend trying to create a smaller sample.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Updated to my most recent tests and sample file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print `0` if a certain value is absent, you could do something like this:

```
val = data[ts][block] ? data[ts][block] : 0;
printf "%s%s", OFS, val
```